# Any way to automatically connect paired bluetooth earphones in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I have a set of BT earphones paired to my Windows 10 laptop. If they're paired to my phone, whenever I turn them on (take them out of the case) they automatically get connected to the phone. However, on Win10, when they're paired (and fully disconnected from the phone, so there's no confusion), they just stay paired and I have to manually connect them each time I take them out of the case.

Is there a way for Windows 10 to automatically connect to the earphones whenever they're turned on?

Comment: If the laptop's Bluetooth is on,  it typically connects automatically.

Comment: I expected this to happen but it doesn't. The laptop's bluetooth is on, but the device stays paired, I have to manually click connect.

Comment: Have you tried removing the earphones in Settings > Devices > Bluetooth & other devices - Audio?

Comment: Yes, it doesn’t help unfortunately.