# Can Windows 10 automatically reconnect to bluetooth headphones when they power up?

Tags: windows, audio, bluetooth

At home, I use a Mac, and I'm used to my mouse, keyboard, and anything else automatically reconnecting with no user intervention if for some reason they power off (changing batteries, usually).

At work, I've now done more remote collaboration these past few months than I have ever. And bluetooth is a royal pain. Since my headphones power off when plugged in for charging, they'll lose their connection (not Windows' fault). But when powered back up, Windows still insists that I open up the bluetooth settings, wait 10 seconds while it does whatever, and then when the device appears I have to select it and click a "connect" button. This is obnoxiously bad.

In comparison, if I pair them with my iPhone, it just works. (I've since unpaired them, I recognize that might confuse things.)

Is there a way for Windows to just auto-connect?

Comment: Perhaps ask the headphone manufacturer for support. I turn different mice off on two different Windows 10 computers with Bluetooth and they re-connect when I turn them back on.

Comment: @John This is a pure Windows problem. The manufacturer has little control over Microsoft's bluetooth stack or its abysmal UI.

Comment: dupe? https://superuser.com/questions/1488414/any-way-to-automatically-connect-paired-bluetooth-earphones-in-windows-10